# how to count dates entries monthwise from a resultset

Tags: java, sql

I am making a database connection and running a sql query which returns me a rsultset with single column of java.util.date type, now in the column i have entries like,

```
2012-03-20 13:50:27.278
2011-08-11 00:30:31.121
2011-08-11 00:35:48.726
2011-08-11 01:18:41.712
2011-08-11 01:20:20.403
2011-08-11 01:22:49.588
2011-08-11 01:25:51.451
2013-02-14 19:39:06.837
2011-08-11 14:46:01.376
2011-08-13 05:43:20.744
2011-08-13 05:46:05.477
2011-08-16 08:07:56.551
2011-08-18 13:21:55.534
2011-08-18 13:23:13.961
2011-08-18 13:33:58.683
2011-08-18 13:36:29.199
2011-08-23 12:02:36.086
2012-12-31 13:49:21.999
2013-02-28 17:49:18.938
2013-05-04 19:17:39.512
2011-09-02 20:17:33.023
2011-09-05 21:50:18.495
2011-09-09 21:14:26
2011-09-09 21:42:48.984
2011-09-09 21:59:27.321
```

and i m thinking of calculating count of entries for each month? any help?

Comment: i know select and i know group by, but im confused how to use it to handle date format type data from table

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: postgres, the entry of the particular column in the table is of timestamp without time zone type

Comment: Couple of points; 1) it returns `java.sql.Date`, not `java.util.Date` and 2) you can do this in SQL with a `group by` clause.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you modify your `SELECT` to use `GROUP BY` on the month?

[In PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP) you could do this:

```
  SELECT count(*), y, m
    FROM t
  -- AND more conditions
GROUP BY extract(year from timecolumn) AS y,
         extract(month from timecolumn) AS m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Format the dates as text using a SimpleDateFormat only outputting the year and month and then count the occurances.

How to do the latter is quite obviuous, e.g. by using a Set where the keys are of the format "yyyy-mm"